# half rectangle shape drawable shapes android

Tags: android, drawable, android-vectordrawable

I use this drawable code:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item  >
    <rotate
        android:fromDegrees="45"
        android:toDegrees="10"
        android:pivotX="100%"
        android:pivotY="-0%">
        <shape
            android:shape="rectangle"   >
            <solid
                android:color="@color/text_color"  />
        </shape>

    </rotate>
</item>
```

And the output is :

[Shape preview after run above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WGPaZ.png)

I want only one little change, i need to show this half square at right like this one :

[Required shape preview](http://saadusman.androidstudent.net/CronaProject/righshape.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this will solve your issue:-

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item  >
    <rotate
        android:fromDegrees="-45"
        android:toDegrees="45"
        android:pivotX="0%"
        android:pivotY="0%">
        <shape
            android:shape="rectangle"   >
            <solid
                android:color="@color/text_color"  />
        </shape>

    </rotate>
</item>
```